# How to click on dynamic list using its xpath. Elements keep changing accordingly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The elements xpath will be like the below one.. and these are dynamic, so sometime, only one will be there.. sometime.. all 3 will be there... etc. so script has to identify with the number of elements appear and click one by one accordingly.

```
public void NumberOfStops(){
    Util.pause(Util.WaitingTime.SHORT);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");
    Util.pause(Util.WaitingTime.SHORT);
    Util.pause(Util.WaitingTime.SHORT);

    List<WebElement> AirlineStops = this.getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("ng-scope layout-row"));
    System.out.println("airlineSize = " + Integer.toString(AirlineStops.size()));
    for ( WebElement stops22 : AirlineStops ) {
            Util.pause(Util.WaitingTime.SHORT);
            stops22.click();
           Util.pause(Util.WaitingTime.SHORT);
    }
```

---

xpaths will be like this.

```
.//*[@id='stops']/div/check-box-switch/div/div[1]/label/div/div/div
.//*[@id='stops']/div/check-box-switch/div/div[2]/label/div/div/div
.//*[@id='stops']/div/check-box-switch/div/div[3]/label/div/div/div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see that a particular div is varying if the no of elements change so
your generic xpath which contains all the varying items will be ;

```
 .//*[@id='stops']/div/check-box-switch/div/
```

so you can do following;

```
 WebElement baseItem= this.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stops']/div/check-box-switch/div"));

 List<WebElement> allItems = baseItem.findElements(By.xpath("/div"));

 for(WebElement item : allItem){

     WebElement currentItem = item;

     //do your action here


 }
```

Comment: Thanks Kushal, what is 'i' here??

Comment: thanks again.. It worked.. but it identified only one element from the list of 3.. any guess ??

Comment: System.out.println("airlineSize = " + Integer.toString(allItems.size()));

above code printed only 1 instead of 3..